# Wordpress, woocommerce password reset link not working

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, passwords, woocommerce, reset

I have a wordpress site using woocommerce. The lost-password template sends an email but does not include the link to follow to reset the password. The code I am using is:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( add_query_arg( array( 'key' => $reset_key, 'login' => rawurlencode( $user_login ) ),
                             wc_get_endpoint_url( 'lost-password', '', wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) )
                             ) ); ?>">
    <?php _e( 'Click here to reset your password', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
```

Does anyone know why this does not send the link in the email?

Comment: The default [`customer-reset-password.php`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/emails/customer-reset-password.php#L31-L32) template does indeed include a reset link. Have you overriden that template in your theme?

Comment: I edited the template with the copy template and view template buttons. Does that mean I have overriden it?

Comment: Before I made the edits, the code did not work, it sent the emails but it did not include a link.

Comment: can you please include the default code? I can then compare it to what I have. Thank You.

Comment: I already linked you to the [default code](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/emails/customer-reset-password.php#L31-L32). If you aren't seeing it then commence standard debugging procedure of switching to a default theme, and one-by-one disabling other plugins.

Comment: Interesting... I replaced my code with yours and got the exact same results, no link. And the code was identical.

Comment: However...when I went to copy the email, there was lots of text that was invisible until it was highlighted...including the link. So it was there all along, just invisible.

Comment: How do I get that to show? i appreciate all your help!

Comment: Also wondering f you know how to generate a new email. when a new user registers they get an email. When I activate their account (change the status to platinum for example) I would like an email to be generated to inform them. There is not an option for that in the email settings. Can that be done? and how?

Comment: Does it work if you stop modifying the email template? I'd start there. Again, disable other plugins, try a default theme. It's borderline impossible to fix something until you know where the error is coming from. As for custom emails, yes that's possible, but is a completely separate question. See [this tutorial](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-add-a-custom-woocommerce-email/) and then post a new question if you need help.

Comment: This code is something I added with a message while the problem was unfixed. This code works and does show the link in the email. I thought maybe it was the difference between printf andphp_e so I tried to do it the password with printf and still the same result, invisible. Since one link will show and the other will not, it is unlikely it is a plugin problem, I thought.

Comment: Here is the code that does produce a visible link:
<p><?php printf( __( 'You can access your account to view your orders: %s.', 'woocommerce' ), wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ); ?></p>

Comment: <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', $email ); ?>
This code for the footer is weird too, the link for the email in the shows up, but I discovered the restof it (name, address other text) is also invisible.

Comment: I added the font tag to the code for reset link, turns out it was printing in white which was why it was invisible. Not sure why the font color in the heneral email settings did not control that. any clues?

Comment: I'm having a hard time following you. I would suggest you roll back any theme modifications, disable other plugins, and ask a new question explaining what exactly you are trying to do. How do you need to deviate from the default?

Comment: I figured it out. The background color was set to white. the font color of the    footer and the link I was generating was being controlled by the "base color" attribute. When I changed that attribute, I was able to see the footer and the link against the white background. Thanks for your help. Sorry if I confused you.

Comment: Basically the font color and background color were both white which is why it seemed "invisible".